# Get selected item ID to display in customized DispForm javascript

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, list-item, guid

I'm using SharePoint Online and have a SharePoint-hosted app.

I have a page with a question form that send data in to SharePoint. I show my question form in my DispForm for my list (I added my app as an app part) on DispForm. When I select a item and press on view item I see my question form just as I like it but I don't know how to get the right ID of that item I want to show. Someone have any suggestion? I use

```
listItem.set_item('Title', $('#Title').val());
```

to send data in to my SharePoint list and

and get_fieldValues to read it back

```
$('#Title').val(item.get_fieldValues().Title);
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant parts of your code and tell what's going wrong. It doesn't work here like "here's my problem and my code, solve it please".

Comment: Is it ok for you now?

Comment: You can retrieve it from the query string? It's parameter ID from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done and working like i want it

```
itemId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('ID'));

if (itemId != 'undefined'){
    item = list.getItemById(itemId);
}

 if (itemId != 'undefined'){
        listItem = item;
    }
    else{
        var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(), listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);
    }
```